# In Spring Security (Spring Boot 2.x) how do I provide my own implementation for @Pre/PostAuthorize and checking roles?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, roles

I want to use the built in Spring `@PreAuthorize` annotations and `hasRole`, `hasAnyRole`, etc but have the Spring classes call my implementation to determine if it should be true/false. How would I do this?

Is there a configuration in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I can override?

Do I need to implement a `SecurityExpressionRoot` class? And if so, where do I tell it to use mine?

I tried overriding the access decision manager and adding my own voter, but even though it calls my method and I return `true` (and it's an `AffirmativeBased` manager), it still goes to `SecurityExpressionRoot.hasAnyRole()` which then returns false.

```
public class MyDecisionVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<Object>
{
    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute)
    {
        //We want to always be called
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        //We want to always be called
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes)
    {
        //For testing purposes
        return ACCESS_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

The manager

```
public class MyAffirmativeBasedDecisionManager extends AffirmativeBased
{
    public MyAffirmativeBasedDecisionManager(List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> decisionVoters)
    {
        super( decisionVoters );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz)
    {
        for ( AccessDecisionVoter<?> voter : this.getDecisionVoters() )
        {
            if ( voter.supports( clazz ) )
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Configuring

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true )
public class MyConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        //Turn on OAuth
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .accessDecisionManager( createDecisionManager() );
    }

    private AccessDecisionManager createDecisionManager()
    {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();

        ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice expressionAdvice = new ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice();
        expressionAdvice.setExpressionHandler( new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() );

        decisionVoters.add( new MyDecisionVoter() );
        decisionVoters.add( new PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter( expressionAdvice ) );
        decisionVoters.add( new RoleVoter() );
        decisionVoters.add( new AuthenticatedVoter() );

        return new MyAffirmativeBasedDecisionManager( decisionVoters );
    }
}
```

This should let them in, but it fails with a 403:

```
@GetMapping( "shouldallow" )
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize( "hasRole('ROLE_NOT_EXIST')" )
public String shouldAllow()
{
    return "should allow";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")` call your method instead of the one in `SecurityExpressionRoot`, then, yes, you'd need to replace that by exposing your own `MethodSecurityExpressionHandler` as a bean. You'd override its `createSecurityExpressionRoot` method:

```
class MyExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionOperations
        createSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication a, MethodInvocation mi) {
        return new MyRoot(super.createSecurityExpressionRoot(a, mi));
    }
}

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
class UsingCustomExpressionHandler extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new MyExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

**BUT**, there are less invasive things that you can try first.

### Using a Bean

For example, you can [refer to any of your own beans inside a SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web-beans). So, if you created a `@Bean` that can perform the evaluation, then you don't need to call `hasRole`. Instead, you can just do:

```
@PreAuthorize("@myBean.evaluate(authentication)")
```

It gives you a lot of flexibility to do whatever you need to do with the `Authentication` to determine access.

### Mapping Authorities

Or, you can consider mapping whatever you have in the way of custom roles into a set of `GrantedAuthority`s. Several of the authentication mechanisms in Spring Security come with a way to map custom authority representations.

For example, I noticed your comment `// turn on OAuth`. If you are wanting to override `hasRole` because of OAuth scopes, you can use `oauth2ResourceServer()` and [supply a custom `JwtAuthenticationConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver-authorization-extraction) to adapt your custom authorities into `GrantedAuthority`s. In which case, `hasRole` might not have to be overridden at all. (Of course, I don't know what your specific situation is regarding how you are authenticating the user. This is just one example of `GrantedAuthority` conversion among many.)

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it is one solution but I actually solved the problem by defining an `AccessDecisionManager` and a `AccessDecisionVoter`

Answer (score 4):

It might help:

```
public class AuthorizationService {

public boolean hasAccess(Object obj) {
 // your code here
}
}

@GetMapping( "/someurl" )
@PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.hasAccess(#obj)")
public void dummyMethod(@PathVariable("obj") Object obj) {
}
```

if you define the permission based on some object, you can pass it directly to the method. Otherwise you can ignore argument in `hasAccess` method. And you should provide `bean` of `AuthorizationService`.

Comment: how does that help when someone uses `hasRole`?

Comment: @DonRhummy just change hasAccess to hasRole, conceptually they are the same